# Selenium Issue - Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector" - Need help fixing this

Tags: python, selenium

I need to fix this code. This comes with an error message saying

```
 NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="login_username"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

The below is the code

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    # finq credentials
    username = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    password = "xxxxxxxxx"
    # initialize the Chrome driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\snyder\data\chromedriver.exe')
    # head to finq login page
    driver.get("https://www.finq.com/en/login")
    # find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys(username)
    # find password input field and insert password as well
    driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys(password)
    # click login button
    driver.find_element_by_name("submit_login").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in iframe, so you need to switch to it before interaction.

you can use the below `css_selector` to switch to iframe :

```
iframe[id='login']
```

in code :

```
username = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.finq.com/en/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id='login']")))
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys(username)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys(password)
# click login button
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='submit_login']").click()
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code is working. but im getting an error message  saying NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="submit"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

Comment: okay updated the code above. use this instead `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='submit_login']").click()`

Comment: seems like theres an error too. This is the message. InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159). I have selected the specific ID's by going through inspect element option. Username and password is okay. But I feel the login name is wrong.

Comment: please use this line `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='submit_login']").click()` to click on login button, I could do it from my end, also I see `Incorrect username or password.` since the creds are not correct .